# ¿Cómo filtrar texto en un body de google docs para cambiar su estilo?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, latex, google-documentos

Quiero filtrar un texto Latex que proviene de un google docs primero para eliminar etiquetas como `\section{}` o incluso para cambiar el estilo en Google Docs. El verdadero propósito esta de transformar un código fuente de Latex en un verdadero google docs.

```
\section{La Région-capitale : une place et un rôle exceptionnels}
\subsection{Une longue construction historique}
\subsection{Région-capitale, État et pouvoir politique}
\subsection{Une Région au cœur du pouvoir économique et financier}
\section{De profondes mutations démographiques et économiques}
\subsection{Une région jeune, dynamique et attractive}
\subsection{Un marché du travail et de la formation métropolitain}
\subsection{Le système productif francilien et ses dynamiques}
\begin{itemize}
    \item La première r agricole avec un tiers de la
valeur ajoutee nationale grace aux sols tres fertiles de sa vaste cuvette sedi-mentaire.
    \item L'industrie francilienne se caractérise par le poids des grands groupes, un vaste tissu de petites et moyennes entreprises et l'importance des petites entre prises innovantes
    \item Les services périproductifs et les services aux entreprises sont en plein boom depuis trois décénies
    \item Dans les transports l'IdF est le premier noeud logistique national et un carrefour des échanges nationaux européens et internationaux
    \item I’ile-de-France s'afirme comme la premiére r touristique nationale
\end{itemize}
```

Por lo momento pienso que solo puedo eliminar las etiquetas con el siguiente codigo :

```
function myFunction() {
  // Open a document by ID.
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  //
  body.replaceText("\section", "");
}
```

Por lo tanto, **¿cómo cambiar el estilo del texto entre las etiquetas y eliminarlas?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el siguiente ejemplo en lugar de usar `body.getText();` estoy usando `paragraphs[i].editAsText();` con la finalidad de que el cambio se aplique al texto de cada párrafo y he agregado la condición de que sólo se aplique el formato de texto a los párrafos que inicien empaten con el siguiente patrón: `\.*{`.

```
function myFunction() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var paragraphs = body.getParagraphs();
  // Define a custom paragraph style.
  var style = {};
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] =
    DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT;
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Calibri';
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 18;
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true;
  var searchPattern1 = '\.*{';
  var searchPattern2 = '}';
  for(var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++){
    var text = paragraphs[i].editAsText();
    if(text.findText(searchPattern1)){
      text.replaceText(searchPattern1, '');
      text.replaceText(searchPattern2, '');
      text.setAttributes(style);
    }
  }
  doc.saveAndClose();
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias ! Me permite aprender javascript ! Es genial ! La próxima vez intentaré diferenciar `\section` from `\subsection`