# Script para convertir una lista de Google Docs en una lista LaTex

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, latex, google-documentos

Tengo un google doc y quiero transformarlo en formato LaTex con javascript :

```
- Taxation des Gafa (Irlande et Luxembourg opposé)
- Régulation 
- truc
- truc
- autres trucs
```

Aqui esta mi intento :

```
function myFunction() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var paragraphs = body.getParagraphs();
  // Define a custom paragraph style.
  var style = {};
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.HORIZONTAL_ALIGNMENT] = 
    DocumentApp.HorizontalAlignment.RIGHT; // es necesario ?
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_FAMILY] = 'Calibri'; // es necesario ?
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.FONT_SIZE] = 18; // es necesario ?
  style[DocumentApp.Attribute.BOLD] = true; // es necesario ?
  var searchPattern1 = '-'; 
  for(var i = 0; i < paragraphs.length; i++){
    var text = paragraphs[i].editAsText();
    if(text.findText(searchPattern1)){
      text.replaceText(searchPattern1, '\item');
      text.setAttributes(style);
    }
  }
  doc.saveAndClose();
}
```

Pero no funciona. Me gustaría que hay también el

```
\begin{itemize}
\item 
\item
...
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que no funciona? ¿Obtienes un mensaje de error? ¿Ya revisaste la transcripción de la ejecución? Ref. [mcve].

Comment: Relacionado: [¿Cómo filtrar texto en un body de google docs para cambiar su estilo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/231655/65)

Comment: Yo te recomendaría mirar [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) para conversiones de formatos de texto.

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que el Documento de Google **solo** tiene párrafos que empiezan con `-` , el siguiente código funciona:

```
function myFunction() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  var text = doc.getBody().editAsText();
  text.insertText(0, '\\begin{enumerate}\n');
  text.appendText('\n\\end{enumerate}');
  text.replaceText('^- ','\\item ');
  doc.saveAndClose();
}
```

Y este es un ejemplo antes y después de ejecutarse:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Posibles problemas (con el intento que subiste)

Como `searchPattern1 = '-'`, el inconveniente surge dentro del `if`, pues:

```
text.replaceText(searchPattern1, '\item');
```

Eso hace que expresiones de la forma `- La resta de 10-3 es 7` cambien por `\item La resta de 10\item3 es 7` por lo que se pierde la semántica del párrafo.

---

Esta información la encontré en la documentación de Google Apps Script (función [replaceText](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph#replacetextsearchpattern,-replacement)), si tienes más dudas sobre el manejo de párrafos en Google Documentos puedes visitar [aquí](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/paragraph), o si tienes dudas sobre el uso de expresiones regulares en JS puedes visitar [aquí](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp)